# Can I dynamically style SVG images with my HTML, CSS, and SVG all in separate files, without any JavaScript?

Tags: html, css, svg

I've seen several examples online showing how to import SVG images into HTML and style them using CSS contained in a separate CSS. However, things get tricky when it comes to *dynamically* styling SVG.

Let's say I have an application that supports different themes. A user can swap themes while the application is running. For our purposes here, the theming mechanism is encapsulated somewhere. Whether it uses custom properties or some parsing technique is irrelevant. We shouldn't try any funny stuff to work around the mechanism. **No JavaScript**.

I have the following styled SVG I want to display, such as for a button icon:

```xml
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href=".path/to/styles/app.css" ?>
<svg>
    <circle class="left-circle" cx="33" cy="50" r="33" fill="red" />
    <circle class="right-circle" cx="66" cy="50" r="33" fill="green" />
</svg>
```

The SVG is imported in the HTML using an `<object>` tag. The HTML uses the same stylesheet as the SVG:

```
<link rel-"stylesheet" href=".path/to/styles/app.css" data-theme-hook="true"/>
<button>
    <object type="image/svg+xml" data="./path/to/images/button.svg"></object>
    <span>The Button</span>
</button>
```

The `data-theme-hook` attribute is what tells the theming mechanism to work its magic. The CSS looks like this:

```
button {
    color: black; /* Theming mechanism knows how to swap */
    background-color: white;  /* Theming mechanism knows how to swap */
}
.left-circle {
    fill: green; /* Theming mechanism knows how to swap */
}
.right-circle {
    fill: red; /* Theming mechanism knows how to swap */
}
```

Now, this all works pretty well. I start up my application, and I see my button with the SVG image in it. The trouble occurs when I swap themes. Everything in the HTML proper changes colors as expected. But the SVG elements' colors remain fixed, perhaps because the SVG is in a separate document, and the styles imported via `xml-stylesheet` are static....

To me, this sounds like this should be a pretty straightforward scenario. Am I just doing things wrong? Or is this just not possible without JavaScript interference?